# Laravel 5 failing on large database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, laravel, laravel-5

I am following a [simple ToDo list example](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/creating-a-basic-todo-application-in-laravel-5-part-1/) to learn Laravel 5.
I set up the code exactly as given, and for a small DB, the APP works perfectly.

The problem arose when I set up **my custom seeds (large DB)** (files attached below).
When I set the project count to **~10-50, the APP works perfectly**.
Setting it in the **~1000+ range (1k projects, 100k tasks)**, I have to click (APP query URL) multiple times to even get a delete task to work. Standard methods `delete`, `update` fail, only `store` works. Any idea why?

I have verified using phpMyAdmin that the DB was set up correctly. I have also set up an `Exception` check when deleting.

EDIT: I find that `store` operation is working perfectly even on a 100k database. And if I delete something I just `store`d (using PHP app), it works. However, for the seeded entries, `delete` fails (at least 5 tries).

**ProjectsTableSeeder.php**

http://pastebin.com/HZrZNQgC

**TasksTableSeeder.php**

http://pastebin.com/uB03uTTa

**TasksController.php**

http://pastebin.com/xuACA29B

Original files (from tutorial) are [here](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/laravel-5-todo-tutorial/tree/tutorial-1/database/seeds).

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're seeing - do you get an error message? You mention multiple clicks to get something to delete - is it just really slow?

Comment: Yeah, I checked the logs, no error. There is no exception either. I verified that the input is correctly received by dumping the array. It just redirects, no state change. Like I mentioned, for a small DB, no issues.

Comment: I am using Apache and MariaDB (MySQL) on Arch Linux.

Comment: How are your indexes defined for the tables? Missing or incorrect indexes may cause an impressive increase in processing times.

Comment: Index is an auto-incrementing `id`. The problem was I was generating non-unique slugs using `Faker` (which Laravel translates to id automatically), as I describe in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to display too many records at once.

Try adding this to your index method.

```
public function index(Project $project) {
    return view('tasks.index', compact('project'))->paginate(20);;
}
```

You can display it in your view with.

```
{!! $project->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

I don't believe there is any more set up than that.

The documentation on [pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination) is pretty good.

If you haven't checked out [Laracasts](http://www.laracasts.com) it is worth every dime.

Check out [Crazy Simple Pagination](https://laracasts.com/lessons/crazy-simple-pagination) for more about pagination.

Comment: No, I mean the seeds are working. I verified the db using phpMyAdmin, checking id ranges as well. I meant that when I query using the app, for large databases, the APP IS NOT WORKING. DB seeds fine.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 maybe you could post that code. Also can you give more information about how it isn't working. Is it just slow or no responsive? Is it behaving differently then expected?

Comment: I attached [TasksController.php](http://pastebin.com/xuACA29B)  in the question as well. This is the file that for the APP that interacts with the DB using `Eloquent`. Like I said, for a small DB, this code works. No logical errors.

Comment: Well, I only trying out to-do so I don't bother with pagination. Chrome handles 1k entries though (I didn't add any CSS)! Nice idea though!

Comment: Chrome deals with front end technologies like ember.js or angular. Where it sounds like you are having issue with is the back end. In this case it will not matter which browser you use. Your issue isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out I had mistakenly relied on `Faker` to generate 100k slugs, which was the problem. The multiple clicks for delete were actually different entries being deleted (:P).

I change the slug generating function from:

`'slug' => $faker->firstName`

to:

`'slug' => $faker->firstName.$faker->lastName.rand(0, $BATCH_SIZE)`

and now it works perfectly fine! Phew.
(I had `1k` projects, `1M` tasks, and nearly no lag!)